# Need help converting a curl API request to Google APP Script UrlFetchApp request

Tags: curl, google-apps-script

According to the API documentation, the curl request should be:

```
$data =array (&#39;currentPage&#39; =&gt; 1,
&#39;itemsPerPage&#39; =&gt; 10
);
$hash = sha1(http_build_query($data) . sha1(&#39;password&#39;));
$requestData = array(
&#39;code&#39; =&gt; ‘usercode&#39;,
&#39;username&#39; =&gt; &#39;username&#39;,
&#39;data&#39; =&gt; $data,
&#39;hash&#39; =&gt; $hash);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, &#39;https://mktp-stage.emag.ro/api-3/vat/read&#39;);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, &#39;POST&#39;);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($requestData));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

My App script is:

```
var headers = {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Authorization": "Basic "+ Utilities.base64Encode(user+":"+password)
};

var options = {
"method" : "POST",
"headers" : headers,
"payload" : {
"modifiedAfter" : "2018-12-31 01:00:00",
"status" : 4
}
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
```

I get the results but not filtered by  "modifiedAfter" : "2018-12-31 01:00:00",
    "status" : 4. 
What I am doing wrong?

UPDATE: I used Dimu Designs example but the results are still not filtered.
They(API owner) said that I should send the filters in an array like in the curl request as the API does not accepts json requests but only returns json format:

```
 $data =
    array (
        'currentPage' => 1,
        'itemsPerPage' => 10
);

$hash = sha1(http_build_query($data) . sha1('password'));

$requestData = array(
    'code' => ‘usercode',
    'username' => 'username',
    'data' => $data,
    'hash' => $hash);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($requestData));
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code suffers from two issues.

First, there is a strange caveat with Apps Script where the content type header is set as a property of the `options` object instead of as a property of the `headers` object.

Second you need to `JSON.stringify` your payload object.

So your code should read as:

```
var headers = {
    "Authorization":"Basic "+ Utilities.base64Encode(user+":"+password)
};

var payload = JSON.Stringify({
    "modifiedAfter":"2018-12-31 01:00:00",
    "status":4
});

var options = {
    "method":"POST",
    "contentType":"application/json",
    "headers":headers,
    "payload":payload
};
```